# Trailing slash to remove

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i need to remove the trailing slash, using htaccess, only from the domain URL.

This is my implemented URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.ext [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.it$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the result is that URL without trailing slash goes to the one with trailing slash, I need the opposite.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by _“only from the domain URL”_?

Comment: he wants http:/ /www.example.com  instead of 'http:// www.example.com /' soffy for the weired spaces, but stackoverflow auto format urls

Comment: Yes, on8tom is right!